# Google sheets to reorder data based on the selection number in a draft

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use google sheets to change selection draft data from this form, where the selection number are listed in order next to the items that were selected:

| Pick | selection |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | salad |
| 2 | pizza |
| 3 | pizza |
| 4 | pizza |
| 5 | bread |
| 6 | carrots |
| 7 | pizza |
| 8 | apples |
| 9 | apples |
| 10 | pizza |
| 11 | salad |

into this form

| Food |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apples | 8 | 9 |  |  |  |
| carrots | 6 |  |  |  |  |
| bread | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| salad | 1 | 11 |  |  |  |
| pizza | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 10 |

If anyone knows how to do this in google sheets or excel. I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula to knock it out. See [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bL4OciUUzPRay47i8l90tcLBxq3hkiX6xY_hPdD5oH8/edit#gid=0).
Here's the formula I used in cell `A18`

```
=Sort(UNIQUE(B2:B12),1,true)
```

And this is the respective formula in each `B18:B22`

```
=transpose(filter($A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$B$12=A18))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a single formula.

For the purposes here, I'll assume that your original data is in the range A2:B, and that the data may expand indefinitely downward. Given this, we can't put the formula I will propose below anywhere in Columns A or B, since it would generate a circular reference error. Instead, for the purposes here, let's place the formula in D2, assuming that the entire spreadsheet from D2 rightward and downward is otherwise empty (so that any number of results from A2:B have room to expand.

In D2:

`=ArrayFormula(SORT({UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))<>UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")))),,COUNTA(B2:B))))," ")},1,1))`

Even "cleaner" would be to move the formula to its own sheet, in which case you'd need to be sure to preface each range contained in the formula with the sheet name of the sheet that contains the original data (e.g., Sheet1!B2:B, etc.).

NOTE: This formula was written based on the data types you provided. If your actual data will be different from what you provided, you will get unpredictable results. For instance, if your actual data in the first column is not actually numbers but client names that contain spaces and such, then this formula would need a few adjustments. However, we can only work with what has been provided.